# Permutations with categories (Multinomial Coefficients): formula proof

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, proof-writing, permutations

I am searching for the proof of the multinomial coefficients formula (formula in the picture)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKB6D.png)

Any help please?

Comment: Your nomenclature is non-standard. You seem to be asking about multinomial coefficients... but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Exactly, multinomial coefficients is what I am asking about! Just added it to the title for clarification.

Comment: Please don’t rely on images, and use MathJax. Images cannot be searched, they don’t adjust to different displays, and they cannot be processed by screenreaders, making your post inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

They are all just different forms of the multinomial coefficient.

Since there are $m_i$ repetitions of $x_i$, with $\sum m_i = n$, using the formula for permutations with repetitions, we immediately get

$\dfrac{n!}{m_1!m_2!...m_i!}$, but more usually written as $\dbinom{n}{m_1,m_2,...m_i}$

You should be able to see that the other two forms are also the same formula presented differently.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe my question was unclear at first. I am searching for the proof of the formula

Comment: If you have a number string $111222233$, have you not been taught that the number of permutations will be $\frac{9!}{3!4!2!}$? The denominator is to remove permutations *between* each distinct category. Because , say taking $1s$, whether they appear 111... or 12311 or anywhere in the string, they are all the same. If you need a detailed formal approach, look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#:~:text=The%20multinomial%20coefficients%20have%20a,second%20bin%2C%20and%20so%20on.

Comment: Starts to make sense now! Thank you

Comment: Glad to be of help. Btw, I wrote the comment in a tearing hurry (it's very late here), what I more precisely meant to convey about the three $1's$ is that if they were placed $111...$, we can't create additional permutations by permuting the $1's,$ so we divide by $3! $(for the $1's$) Similarly for other numbers that are repeated.

Comment: I understand your point. It was of a great help! Thank you